# Does the Instagram api have an health-check endpoint?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

E.g. Facebook provides a health-check endpoint at https://www.facebook.com/platform/api-status/. However, the Instagram developer documentation does not seem to provide any such endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram's api is terrible for the moment. As far as i know it does not have any health-check endpoint.
I hope they will release some stable api, because i'm tired to parse their pages and get needed info